# Setting up oauth2 with loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, oauth-2.0

So I'm willing to set up oauth2 for my loopback-based api. I've read lots and lots of documentation on how it works. Now, when I try to apply it on my api, the only true piece of documentation I found was [this](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/OAuth-2.0.html). I'll be clear, I don't get it. I understand that I have to call `oauth2.oAuth2Provider()` with the specified parameters, probably before starting my server, but that's all. How do I supply the URL that will be used to actually get an authorization token (seems like it is in the options, I did try that, but still had a nice "Unauthorized" - 401 as a response) ? When should I call `oauth2.authenticate()` ? How is the token actually formed ? Do I get to decide its expiration time ?  Why should I supply a login page if I can ask for a token with a 'password' grant ? Also, I tried to set up and run [this](https://github.com/strongloop-archive/strong-gateway) but unfortunately, it's telling me that I don't have a valid Strongloop API Gateway lincense.